# What happen if execlp dont include NULL?

Tags: c, exec

If I have the code:

```
execlp("ls", "ls", "-la"); 
exit(1)
```

What is the return value of the process?
The value returned for `ls`?
`1`?
The execution never ends because don't has `NULL`?

Answer (score 2):

> What happen if execlp dont include NULL?

`execlp()` would invoke undefined behaviour be trying to access arguments which had not been passed.

The `(char*) NULL` marks the end of the list of arguments passed to `execlp()`.

As the result of invoking undefined behaviour anything could happen from that moment on.

Answer (score 2):

`execlp` expects a variable number of arguments. So it searches the stack until it finds a NULL argument **and uses those arguments**. As you have not passed those arguments, you will essentially invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Nitpicking: "*... finds a `(char*) NULL` ...*"

Comment: nope, `NULL` is normally defined as plain `0`, as there's compatibility between `int` constant `0` and `whatever *` (for historical reasons).  So `NULL` is perfectly valid to be used mixed with pointers of any kind (not only `char *`) and integers.  No need for the cast.

Answer (score 0):

The `execlp` or other `exec` family function does not return on suceed, they only return `-1` if there is any error. Also according to the man page, the last argument must be a null pointer.

> The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.  Together  they  describe  a
>          list  of  one  or  more  pointers  to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the executed program.  The first argument, by convention,
>          should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.  The list of arguments must be terminated by a null pointer,  and,  since  these  are  variadic
>          functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.